# Can I expose a commonjs module object in the global namespace?

Tags: node.js, webpack, commonjs

We're building a react/flux application using nodejs/webpack and therefore all of our new code is written in commonjs modules.

There are a few isolated cases where we need to access an object from one of our commonjs modules in legacy code. Is there any way to do this...and yes, I assume this is gross. We're eventually going to migrate all of our code to commonjs modules, but this is a stop-gap.

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem using `window.YourNamespace.YourObject = YourObject;` right before your `return YourObject;`?

Comment: Hmmmm I tried window.myObject and that didn't work. I didn't try throwing it into a namespace...would that make a difference? I'll give it a shot ;p

Comment: Why didn't that work? What's the error? You can access `window` in a CommonJS module, that should not be the problem. It's probably a timing issue. Your code tries to access the global object before the CommonJS module is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the legacy JS code (non using CommonJS), create a function in the global namespace:

```
/* Legacy code NOT using CommonJS */
function getCommonJSObject(obj) {
...
}
```

In the CommonJS code you can test for this global function and if it exists, call it, passing whichever object you need access to.

```
/* CommonJS object */
if(window['getCommonJSObject']){
  window.getCommonJSObject(obj);
}
```

By doing this we can still follow our flux pattern from legacy javascript code in our app. If there's a better way to do this, let us know. But this is a handy workaround.